# MultiHeadAttention attention_mask [Keras, Tensorflow] example

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transformer-model, attention-model

I am struggling to mask my input for the MultiHeadAttention Layer. I am using the Transformer Block from Keras documentation with self-attention. I could not find any example code online so far and would appreciate if someone could give me a code snippet.

The transformer block from [this](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_with_transformer/) page:

```
class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__()
        self.att = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
        self.ffn = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)
```

The documentation for masking one can find under [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention) link:

> attention_mask: a boolean mask of shape [B, T, S], that prevents
> attention to certain positions. The boolean mask specifies which query
> elements can attend to which key elements, 1 indicates attention and 0
> indicates no attention. Broadcasting can happen for the missing batch
> dimensions and the head dimension.

The only thing, I could get running is a mask created outside of the layer class as numpy array:

```
mask = np.ones((observations, sequence_length, sequence_length))
mask[X[:observations,:,0]==0]=0
```

Then input while calling the layer, with the only change in the transformer block being:

```
def call(self, inputs, mask, training):
    attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs, attention_mask=mask)
```

However, this does of course not work when given a batch_size while fitting and does only work for 5 observations with my memory, so it doesn't make any sense.
Apart from that, I don't think this is masking the input properly - In general I am quite confused about how to mask, given the shape of the attention_mask (observations, sequence_length, sequence_length). The shape of my input is (observation, sequence_length, features). This input is being padded by zeros, however, when it comes to the transformer block, it has been already through an embedding layer and CNN.
I have tried various ways to write a function, which creates the mask while training with different Tensor or Keras objects. However I am running each time into errors.

I hope someone more fluent in Tensorflow/Keras will be able to provide an example.
Or somebody tells me that masking is useless given my architecture. The model is performing well. However, I hoped masking could help speed up the computing.
And it just buggs me that I cannot get my head around it.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe it is a little bit late, but for anyone who ends up on this post looking for a solution, this may help.

A typical scenario using a Transformer is in a NLP problem, where you have batches of sentences (let's assume that they are already tokenized for simplicity). Consider the following example:

```
sentences = [['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'], ['Integer', 'tincidunt', 'in', 'arcu', 'nec', 'fringilla', 'suscipit']]
```

As you can see, we have two sentences of different lenght. In order to learn from them in a tensorflow model, we can pad the shortest one with a special token, let's say `'[PAD]'`, and feed them into a Transformer model, as you proposed. Hence:

```
sentences = tf.constant([['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', '[PAD]', '[PAD]'], ['Integer', 'tincidunt', 'in', 'arcu', 'nec', 'fringilla', 'suscipit']])
```

Also assuming that we already have a vocabulary of tokens extracted from some corpus, for example a vocabulary of `1000` tokens, we can define a `StringLookup` layer that converts our batch of sentences into their numerical projections given the vocabulary. And we can specify which token is used for **masking**.

```
lookup = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocabulary, mask_token='[PAD]')
x = lookup(sentences)
# x is a tf.Tensor([[2, 150, 19, 997, 9, 0, 0], [72, 14, 1, 1, 960, 58, 87]], shape=(2, 7), dtype=int64)
```

where we can see that the `[PAD]` token maps to the **0** value in the vocabulary.

A typical next step is to feed this Tensor into an `Embedding` layer, something like this:

```
embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=lookup.vocabulary_size(), output_dim=64, mask_zero=True)
```

The key here is the argument `mask_zero`. As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding), this argument means:

> Boolean, whether or not the input value 0 is a special "padding" value that should be masked out...

This allows the `embedding` layer to generate a mask for the subsequent layers to indicate which positions should be attended and which should not. This mask can be accessed via:

```
mask = embedding.compute_mask(sentences)
# mask is a tf.Tensor([[True, True, True, True, True, False, False], [True, True, True, True, True, True, True]], shape=(2, 7), dtype=bool)
```

The tensor of the embeddings is of the form:

```
y = embedding(sentences)
# y is a tf.Tensor of shape=(2, 7, 64), dtype=float32)
```

In order to use the `mask` into the `MultiHeadAttention` layer, the mask must be reshaped to accomplish with the shape requirements, which per the documentation is `[B, T, S]` where `B` means the *batch size* (2 in the example), `T` means the **query size** (7 in our example), and `S` means the **key size** (again 7 if we are using self attention). Also in a multihead attention layer we must take care of the number of heads `H`. The easiest way of creating a compatible mask with this input is via broadcasting:

```
mask = mask[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]
# mask is a tf.Tensor of shape=(2, 1, 1, 7), dtype=bool) -> [B, H, T, S]
```

Then we can finally feed the `MultiHeadAttention` layer as follows:

```
mha = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=4, key_dim=64)
z = mha(y, y, attention_mask=mask)
```

So in order to use, your `TransformerBlock` layer with a mask, you should add to the `call` method a `mask` argument, as follows:

```
def call(self, inputs, training, mask=None):
    attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs, attention_mask=mask)
    ...
```

And in the layer/model where you are calling the `MultiHeadAttention` layer, you must pass/propagate the mask that you generated with the `Embedding` layer.

Comment: "mask is a tf.Tensor of shape=(2, 1, 1, 7), dtype=bool) -> [B, H, T, S]".


Shouldn't the shape of the mask be `(2,4,7,7)` accounting for the number of heads `H = 4` and self-attention `T = S = 7`?

Comment: Yes, but you can take advantage of "Broadcasting". So, you can leave these dimensions to `1` and broadcasting will map them to the corresponding dimensions when you operate with this tensor. I mean, you are right, but there is no need to fully specify the whole tensor dimensions thanks to broadcasting.