# How to mask inputs with variable size in transformer model when the batches needs to be masked differently?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, transformer-model

I'm making a transformer using `tensorflow.keras` and having issues understanding how the `attention_mask` works for a `MultiHeadAttention` layer.

My input is 3-dimensional data. For example, let's assume my whole dataset has 10 elements, each one with length no more than 4:

```py
# whole data
[
  # first item
  [
    [     1,      2,      3],
    [     1,      2,      3],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
  ],
  # second item
  [
    [     1,      2,      3],
    [     5,      8,      2],
    [     3,      7,      8],
    [     4,      6,      2],
  ],
  ... # 8 more items
]
```

So, my mask looks like:

```py
# assume this is a numpy array
mask = [
  [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ],
  [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
  ],
  ...
]
```

So the shape of the mask til now is `[10, 4, 3]`. Let's say I use `batch_size = 5`. Now, according documentation, `attention_mask` shape should be `[B, T, S]` (batch_size, query_size, key_size). In the example case should be `[5, 4, 4]`?

### Question

**If the mask is calculated only once, what 5 items should I give as a mask? This sounds counterintuitive to me. How should I build the mask?**

According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805117/multiheadattention-attention-mask-keras-tensorflow-example) answer, head_size should be also taken in account, so they also do:

```py
mask = mask[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]
```

### What I've tested

The only time I manage to run the transformer successfully using the `attention_mask` is when I do:

```py
mask = np.ones((batch_size, data.shape[1], data.shape[2]))
mask = mask[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]
```

Obviously that mask makes no sense, because it is all ones, but it was just to test if it had the correct shape.

### The model

I'm using practically the same code from the `keras` [example](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_classification_transformer/) transformer for time series classification

```py
def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0.0, mask=None):
    # Normalization and Attention
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(inputs)
    x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
    )(x, x, attention_mask=mask)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    return x + res


def build_model(
    n_classes,
    input_shape,
    head_size,
    num_heads,
    ff_dim,
    num_transformer_blocks,
    mlp_units,
    dropout=0.0,
    mlp_dropout=0.0,
    input_mask=None,
) -> keras.Model:
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = inputs
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):
        x = transformer_encoder(x, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout, input_mask)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format="channels_first")(x)
    for dim in mlp_units:
        x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research and seeing several transformer model examples this is what solved the problem for me.

1. Create a custom `TransformerBlock` layer that supports masking
2. Add a `mask` parameter in the `call` method of the `TransformerBlock` and reshape it there.
3. Add a `Masking` layer before the `TransformerBlock`

Code:

```py
class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, ff_dim2, rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.att = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=head_size)
        self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")
        self.conv2 = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim2, kernel_size=1)
        self.supports_masking = True

    def call(self, inputs, training, mask=None):
        padding_mask = None
        if mask is not None:
            padding_mask = tf.cast(mask[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :], dtype="int32")

        out_norm1 = self.layernorm1(inputs, training=training)
        out_att = self.att(
            out_norm1, out_norm1, training=training, attention_mask=padding_mask
        )
        out_drop1 = self.dropout1(out_att, training=training)
        res = out_drop1 + inputs
        out_norm2 = self.layernorm2(res, training=training)
        out_conv1 = self.conv1(out_norm2, training=training)
        out_drop2 = self.dropout2(out_conv1, training=training)
        out_conv2 = self.conv2(out_drop2, training=training)
        return out_conv2 + res

def build_model(
    n_classes,
    input_shape,
    head_size,
    num_heads,
    ff_dim,
    num_transformer_blocks,
    mlp_units,
    dropout=0.0,
    mlp_dropout=0.0,
    mask=None,
) -> keras.Model:
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    _x = inputs
    if mask is not None:
        _x = layers.Masking(mask_value=mask)(_x)
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):
        _x = TransformerBlock(
            head_size,
            num_heads,
            ff_dim,
            inputs.shape[-1],
            dropout,
        )(_x)

    _x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format="channels_first")(_x)
    for dim in mlp_units:
        _x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(_x)
        _x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(_x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(_x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Answer (score 1):

> First, a simpler example to understand `MultiHeadAttention` mask.

```
#Crude Self attention implementation
query = tf.constant([[1], [2], [3], [4]], dtype=tf.float32)  #Shape([4, 1])

scores = tf.matmul(query, query, transpose_b=True) #Shape([4, 4])
#unnormalized, presoftmax score
```

The above is the `attention scores` for the given query.  `attention_mask` is used when you want to prevent attention to certain positions in this score. So mask dimension should be same as the attention score dimension.

Lets say, we decide that the current token in the above example needs to attend to only itself and to the next token, then we can define mask as:

```
mask = tf.constant([[1., 1., -np.inf, -np.inf],
        [-np.inf, 1., 1. ,-np.inf],
        [-np.inf, -np.inf, 1., 1.],
        [-np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, 1.]])

#apply mask on the score
scores = scores*mask

#softmax 
scores = tf.nn.softmax(scores)

#scores, ( 0 indicates no attention) 
[[0.26894143, 0.73105854, 0.        , 0.        ],
 [0.        , 0.11920292, 0.880797  , 0.        ],
 [0.        , 0.        , 0.04742587, 0.95257413],
 [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ]]

#score weighted queries
value = tf.matmul(scores, query)

#value is a weighted average of the current and next token of ( [[1], [2], [3], [4]])
[[1.7310585], #weighted average of ([1], [2]) (current and next)
 [2.8807971],
 [3.9525743],
 [4.       ]]
```

> Can there be different mask for each item in the batch?.

Yes, a use case i can think of is when you have padding for different samples in the same batch, so the mask can be set to ignore those paddings.

> Your specific case: The mask has to be `(batch_size, 4, 4)`. The mask can be same for each item in the batch.

```
batch_size = 5
query = keras.Input(shape=(4, 3))
mask_tensor = keras.Input(shape=(4, 4))

#keras layer
mha = keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=1, key_dim=3)
output = mha(query=query, value=query, attention_mask=mask_tensor, return_attention_scores=True)

#Create a model
model = keras.Model([query, mask_tensor], output)

#random query and mask. Note the mask needs to be (1:attention or 0:no attention) 
queries = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, 4, 3))
mask_data = tf.random.uniform(maxval=2, shape=(batch_size, 4, 4), dtype=tf.int32)

#calling the model
values, attn_weights = model.predict([queries, mask_data])

#attm_weights.shape
(5, 1, 4, 4)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I still don't understand this: if a batch is a bunch of inputs (each one with a certain padding), shouldn't each batch have its own mask? At the end each batch has a different set of inputs, isn't it? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Each batch can have its own mask.

Comment: I think this is the problem, I'm setting only one mask when building the model. How can I set a mask for each batch? Do I have to create a new class extending the `tf.keras.layers.Layer`?

Comment: You can pass the mask along with inputs like shown here- https://keras.io/examples/nlp/masked_language_modeling/ or you can obtain the mask from the input itself with manipulation like shown here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16248 . If the mask is fixed like in your case, you can do the second link, where you can broadcast to batch-dimension.

Comment: Well, after digging in the those links (plus other transformer examples) I finally came with a solution: Implement my own TransformerBlock layer with `self.supports_masking = True` and using the `mask` parameter in the `call` method. Also, a `Masking` layer needs to be created before the `TransformerBlock`. I'll live this as another answer too. Thanks a lot for you time!!!